# android:how to reload the listview in multiple selection time

Tags: android

Hi Friends I when i click the checkbox..i want to refresh the listview because when i check there are no effect in current view but when i scroll down that is perform so i want to reload the view so how can i reload the view in listview chckbox click event??

Answer (score 1):

u can use listmethod ie notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
  cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View arg0) {
....
```

Where `cb` is a `checkbox`.

Within this listener you can refresh your list adapter, use lv.setAdapter, where lv is setAdapter.

You can also search refreshing a list adapter view you can search setadapter method. I hope that is what you want.